# Add-migration Exeception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

When I try to add-migration I get this error:

```
 PM> add-migration RestrictPromotionContentAndTitle
    System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
       at BrightInfo.Infrastructure.Settings.DbAudit.AuditDbContext..ctor(String connString)
       at BrightInfo.Infrastructure.Settings.BrightInfoContext..ctor(Boolean proxyCreationEnabled, Boolean lazyLoadingEnabled) in C:\Projects\BrightInfo\BrightInfo.Infrastructure.Settings\BrightInfoContext.cs:line 124
       at BrightInfo.Infrastructure.Settings.BrightInfoContext..ctor() in C:\Projects\BrightInfo\BrightInfo.Infrastructure.Settings\BrightInfoContext.cs:line 113
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.<CreateActivator>b__0()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetPendingMigrationsRunner.RunCore()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Who does know how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I forgot to mention when I switch to Package Manager Console I get this error message:

```
    Unable to find type [NuGet.PackageManager]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
At C:\Projects\BrightInfo\packages\T4Scaffolding.Core.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:4 char:5
+ if ([NuGet.PackageManager].Assembly.GetName().Version -lt 1.4)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (NuGet.PackageManager:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Does somebody know how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: What was the last change you've made?

Comment: It's a first time when I try to migrate in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have a dll reference correctly in your project.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
       at ...

If you could add the appropriate dll and clean solution, rebuild the solution and then try again, you should successfully execute. If further error persists, post your migration details found to better understand and help you.

HTH

Comment: Yeah, I have read about this issue https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25424/error-running-entity-framework-6-code-first-migrat.html with relative link and I have changed them to absolute pathes.

Comment: But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it By Adding:
{ get; set; }
To My All Properties